# Criar uma label a partir de um item duma listbox

Tags: c#, button, label, listbox

Eu estou a tentar criar uma aplicação prototipo para mapear uma rede. A aplicação parece assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É constituida por 2 botões, um para scan que vai preencher a lista na direita com os dados pretendidos e um segundo botão (placeholder) que devia criar uma label arrastável (sendo esta a dificuldade) com o texto equivalente ao item da lista que tenho selecionado para que, assim que seja criada, eu possa arrastar essa mesma label para cima do mapa de forma a mapear o computador na minha aplicação.

Já passei por várias tentativas, até agora sem sucesso... nem tenho a certeza de que o quero criar (label arrastavel) ser possivel. Para já ficava já satisfeito com a label em si aparecer.

O que tentei até agora foi:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label lbl = new Label
        {
            Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
        };
    }
```

Tambem tentei integrar a [seguinte solução](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/178587/Draggable-WinForms-Controls) mas sem sucesso.

Peço então aqui, há alguma maneira de criar uma label a partir duma seleção dum item numa listbox? E se sim, é possível essa label ser arrastada durante o runtime?

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Você tá criando o label e não tá adicionando em lugar nenhum.

Comment: No Draggable já testou adicionar o NuGet "Control.Draggable". Ai no código insira a linha: `ControlExtension.Draggable(button1, true);`

Comment: Outra opção seria desenhar o texto em vez de criar uma label

Comment: @Focos Tentei a sua sugestão com o código atual mas ainda sem resultado...

Comment: @LINQ Sou sincero, nao estou habituado a trabalhar com forms em c#, vou pesquisar como especificar um lugar pa label.

Comment: @vik Como procederia para "desenhar o texto"? Pode desenvolver essa ideia por favor?

Comment: @Mako Insere o código no construtor, aqui funcionou dessa forma. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rytt-a2cTJA

Comment: @Mako usando o evento `OnPaint`, difícil explicar só com um exemplo pratico, talvez isto ajude: [Renderizando um controle dos Windows Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/rendering-a-windows-forms-control)